# Bootstrap responsive tab to dropdown, what is missing from my code?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am trying to convert bootstrap tabs to a dropdown menu for smaller screens. Two things I want for my dropdown are:

- The button will first say 'please select' and once a list item is selected, it will be what is showing on the button
- The dropdown still functions like a tab, the tab content will be under the dropdown menu and will change according to what is selected

I've gotten the first point to work by using this in my js file:

```
$('#product-list .dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
   $('#selected').text($(this).text());
});
```

What I noticed with this though is that when I've clicked on multiple items on the list, they are all highlighted as though all active.

With the second point, what I've used enables me to select each item on the list once, but if I go back and try to choose something I've already selected before, it won't change (maybe this has to do with them all being highlighted). The below code is what I've used:

```
<div class="dropdown col-sm-12">
    <button id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
    <span id="selected">Please select a product <span class="caret"></span></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="myTabs" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#aframe" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">A-frames</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#alum" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Alum panel signs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-sm-12">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="aframe">
        <p>Contents of tab panel in here</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="alum">
        <p>Contents of tab panel in here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usually with tabs all I need is to link the tab-content to the nav-tab but I'm obviously missing a few things here. Could someone help me?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need the dropdown toggle to act as the nav pill which can be achievable by adding a

> data-toggle="tab" & href="target id" to the anchor of dropdown toggle

For content changes of the dropdown heading refer the code below in jquery

I have created a [pen](http://codepen.io/thebunny/pen/kXpWZx) for the same effect

```
$(".drop").click(function(){
$(this).parent().removeClass("active");
var content = $(this).text();
$(".dropdown-toggle").text(content+" ");
$(".dropdown-toggle").append("<span class='caret'></span>")
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Just one thing, after clicking both items in the dropdown it appears that they both highlighted blue. Is this something that needs to be fixed or removed with CSS or is it to do with the javascript?

Comment: Yes you would need to alter the active state of anchor link check the same pen i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist"> 
    <li class="dropdown col-sm-12">
        <button id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <span id="selected">Please select a product <span class="caret"></span></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="myTabs" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#aframe" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">A-frames</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#alum" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Alum panel signs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content col-sm-12">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="aframe">
        <p>Contents of tab panel in here</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="alum">
        <p>Contents of tab panel in here Contents of tab panel in here </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check snippet for solution